# Join a set of objects into one object?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a data structure like this:

```
const list = [
  {"hello": "world"},
  {"goodbye": "cruel world"}
]
```

and I want to join it into:

```
{"hello": "world",
 "goodbye": "cruel world"}
```

I can do it semi-elegantly like so:

```
const union = l.reduce((acc, o) => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach((k) => acc[k] = o[k]);
  return acc;
}, {})
```

But is there a more elegant way, perhaps built into the JS standard library?

Comment: Since the code works but you want "elegant" it seems like this would be better suited for CodeReview.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `Object.assign()` and ES6 spread syntax.

```js
const list = [
  {"hello": "world"},
  {"goodbye": "cruel world"}
]

var obj = Object.assign({}, ...list);
console.log(obj)
```